# !runaway error: could not get process information, 6

Tags: iis, windbg

I've got an IIS process CPU issue, for some reason the w3wp.exe always takes 100% CPU. I used to try WinDbg to analyse threads in w3wp dump file, which was very convenient.

But somehow WinDbg is not working now. It keeps showing

> could not get process information, 6

when I use `!runaway`.

The version of sos.dll and clr.dll are correct, and `!clrstack` works fine. Even `.ttime` works fine that I can get run time for single thread.

Just `!runaway` is not working, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well... I suppose I could answer my own question...

The WinDbg I've been using is the UWP version which downloaded from WinStore (WinDbg Preview). That worked fine weeks ago but now we need to do some upgrade.

I download the latest version of WinDbg from this url:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/

Now everything works fine...